# Jenkins pipeline replay multiple files

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, replay

As explain in this post (https://www.cloudbees.com/blog/replay-pipeline), i would like replay a pipeline but with multiple files.

Is it possible ?

Comment: Unclear what you're asking.